# How to fix error related to combination of IF and choose function below?

Tags: excel, vba

I have used choose function to extract data from 4 diff sheets:

`=CHOOSE($H$3,sheet1!A2,sheet2!A2,sheet3!A2,sheet4!A2)`

Now, I want to use "IF" function with CHOOSE to replace the false results with "". But it's not working, is there any problem with syntax below?

```
=IF(CHOOSE($H$3,sheet1!A2,sheet2!A2,sheet3!A2,sheet4!A2),CHOOSE($H$3,sheet1!A2,sheet2!A2,sheet3!A2,sheet4!A2),"")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're getting an error (like #Value) then maybe it's better to use `IFERROR`:

`=IFERROR(CHOOSE($H$3,sheet1!A2,sheet2!A2,sheet3!A2,sheet4!A2),"")`

Comment: yes it worked. But I've formatted my out put sheet into table, so where ever there is no data in the source sheet, I am getting value as 0. Could you please guide me how I have to inculcate the formula to remove that 0.

Comment: Hmm you would need to insert another IF to handle the zeros:

`IF(IFERROR(CHOOSE($H$3,sheet1!A2,sheet2!A2,sheet3!A2,sheet4!A2),"")=0,"",IFERROR(CHOOSE($H$3,sheet1!A2,sheet2!A2,sheet3!A2,sheet4!A2),""))`

Comment: thank you sir, I have used the same formula before ,but forgot to include "" after 0. I think am doing great by making silly mistakes. :). Thanks again.